# what is the best way to render individual child classes differently in a listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

i have a base class called Vehicle. I have derived classes from it called car, Suv, Truck etc.

What I need to be able to do is to bind them to a list view as follows.

```
ListView.DataSource = List<Vehicle>;
ListView.DataBind();
```

The `List<Vehicle>` can be a mix of cars, trucks etc.

On the aspx page, I want to be able to display them according to their vehicletype property.

```
<uc:VehicleView ID="VehicleView" runat="server" VehicleItem='<%#DataBinder.GetDataItem(Container) as Vehicle %>' />
```

This user control will have the correct object in code behind when databound. All these work so far.

The listing page lists only common properties from the vehicle class but need to display different things/layout per vehicle type.

My question is what is the best way to display different data in this single vehicle view control. Have different panels that gets toggled, load different user controls through code, any other options? i would like to keep the html in the aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a [composite databound control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositedataboundcontrol.aspx) you can obtain something like this:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <uc:CVehicleView runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>
            <Car>
                  html for car goes here <%# Eval("SpecificCarProperty") %>
            </Car> 
            <Suv>
                  html for suv goes here <%# Eval("SpecificSuvProperty") %>
            </Suv>
      </uc:CVehicleView>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The implementation might be a bit tricky if you didn't do it before and most of the examples are for lists (for when datasource is a list of objects). You need to override the [CreateChildControls](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2007/01/10/creating-a-custom-databound-templated-control-in-asp-net-2-0.aspx) method and instantiate the proper template (using the type of the item).

DetailsView and FormView are the well known controls designed to show a single item and calling a specific template. But both controls use as DataSource an IEnumerable object, so basically you can't just make a call like `FormView.DataSource = car; FormView.DataBind()`, because car does not implement `IEnumerable`. So having an `IEnumerable` datasource is a bit important.

What you can do is to override DataSource property

```
public class CVehicleView : CompositeDataBoundControl
{
    private object dataSource;
    public override object DataSource
    {
        get { return new List<object> { dataSource }; }
        set { dataSource = value; }
    }
}
```

and the markup would be

```
<asp:ListView runat="server">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <uc:CVehicleView runat="server" VehicleDataSource='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>
 ...
```